# Add data to canvas div's by clicking on rectangle

Tags: javascript, json, canvas

http://fiddle.jshell.net/f6rLds4g/

I have put the data in div's manual (just typing `1111`, `2222`, `333`, `4444`)

My question is is it possible to get data from JSON (which i tried but failed - I think the mistake is on me). I searched for answers on the web but failed to find it.

So if I click on the first rectangle it should give me a data showing in the divs from the JSON file instead of prompt

the JSON is:

```
{
    "name": "1",
    "text": "111111",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "country": "NL"
}
```

So instead of just typing `1111` it should put this data in the first div from a JSON file.

Comment: use JSON.parse to convert json to a jsonObject and then obtain those values and add it

Comment: how do i do that in this script ?

Comment: var jsn = '{
    "name": "1",
    "text": "111111",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "country": "NL"
}';
var jsnObj = JSON.parse(jsn);
jsnObj.country will give NL, jsnObj.version will give 1.0.0.
If this is what you expect let me know i will transfer this to an answer

Comment: @Wishy Sorry for my late reaction Because of some problems I wasn't able to work on the project. I think that this is what i am looking 
Do you know how I code this into my script ?

Comment: does this jsbin help you http://jsbin.com/cehazo/1/edit?js,console

Comment: @Wishy i have the answer on this topic 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30303856/connect-rectangle-with-json?noredirect=1#comment48709070_30303856

but thnx for youre help !!!

Comment: as long as you got what you wanted  : )